# make a div responsive by breaking its elements in two lines

Tags: html, css, responsive-design, css-float

I have a div that contains a menu with 8 buttons in the middle of my page. My problem is to make that  responsive.My idea is to rotate it horizontally and to separate in two lines, each  row/line to contain 4 buttons.
I tied to do it like this:

```
@media (max-width: 767px){
    .icon1{float: left; margin-left: 25px; margin-bottom: 50px;}
    .icon2{float: left; margin-left: 25px; margin-top: 50px;}
     }
```

Here's me css code:

```
  .content .middle-content{
    text-align: center;
    }

.content .middle-content .icon1{
    margin-bottom: 15px;
    margin-top: 15px;
}
.content .middle-content .icon2{
    margin-bottom: 15px;
    margin-top: 15px;
}
```

and my html code:

```
<div class="col-md-2">
        <div class="middle-content"> 
            <div class="icon1">
                <img src="img/clock.png">
            </div>
            <div class="icon1">
                <img src="img/clock.png">
            </div>
            <div class="icon1">
                <img src="img/clock.png">
            </div>
            <div class="icon1">
                <img src="img/clock.png">
            </div>
            <div class="icon2">
                <img src="img/clock.png">
            </div>
            <div class="icon2">
                <img src="img/clock.png">
            </div>
            <div class="icon2">
                <img src="img/clock.png">
            </div>
            <div class="icon2">
                <img src="img/clock.png">
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

I created a jsfiddle  just to give the idea how it looks in general, there are three divs left that some text, the middle div with those buttons and the right one also with text.

Can anyone help me to make it responsive and to separate buttons into two rows? [DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/egzontina/ff0k9j45/9/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a single class on your all your "icon" divs rather than two and then:

```
@media screen and (max-width: 767px) {
    .icon1 {
        float: left;
        width: 25%;
    }
```

[**JSfiddle Demo**](https://jsfiddle.net/0xsatyct/)

Comment: another question if you have time to answer : using  margin-bottom: 50px; margin-top: 50px; has no effect why  is this happening?

Comment: on small screen i want to get a space between  the div with those buttons and div below and above.Using:  margin-bottom: 50px; margin-top: 50px;  gives no effect!

Answer (score 0):

```
   <style>
    .top, .bottom{clear:both;}
    .icon1, .icon2{float: left; margin:10px 0 10px 20px; }
    </style>
    <div class="col-md-2">
            <div class="middle-content">
                <div class="top"> 
                <div class="icon1">
                    <img src="img/clock.png">
                </div>
                <div class="icon1">
                    <img src="img/clock.png">
                </div>
                <div class="icon1">
                    <img src="img/clock.png">
                </div>
                <div class="icon1">
                    <img src="img/clock.png">
                </div>
                </div>
                <div class="bottom">
                <div class="icon2">
                    <img src="img/clock.png">
                </div>
                <div class="icon2">
                    <img src="img/clock.png">
                </div>
                <div class="icon2">
                    <img src="img/clock.png">
                </div>
                <div class="icon2">
                    <img src="img/clock.png">
                </div>
            </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```